# Perl Constant seems not to work

Tags: perl, constants

I have this:

```
use constant JAR_FILE => qr/\.jar$/;

my @dir_list = ...;
my @jar_list;
find ( sub {
    return unless -f;
    return unless JAR_FILE;   #THIS IS THE TROUBLED LINE
    push @jar_list, $File::Find::name;
    }, @dir_list;

say join ": ", @jar_list;
```

This prints out all of the files in `@dir_list` -- jar files and non jar files;

However, this:

```
use constant JAR_FILE => qr/\.jar$/;

my @dir_list = ...;
my @jar_list;
find ( sub {
    return unless -f;
    return unless $_ =~ JAR_FILE;  #Now explicitly do the comparison 
    push @jar_list, $File::Find::name;
    }, @dir_list;

say join ": ", @jar_list;
```

prints out only jar files.

And this also only prints out jar files:

```
# use constant JAR_FILE => qr/\.jar$/;

my @dir_list = ...;
my @jar_list;
find ( sub {
    return unless -f;
    return unless /\.jar$/;  #Use regex and not constant regex. 
    push @jar_list, $File::Find::name;
    }, @dir_list;

say join ": ", @jar_list;
```

Why does the first one `return unless JAR_FILE;` not work while `return unless $_ =~ JARFILE;` and `return unless /\.jar$/;` both work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has nothing to do with constants.

```
>perl -wE"$_ = '.txt'; say qr/\.jar$/ ?1:0;"
1

>perl -wE"$_ = '.txt'; say /\.jar$/ ?1:0;"
0

>perl -wE"$_ = '.txt'; say $_ =~ qr/\.jar$/ ?1:0;"
0
```

`qr//` compiles a regex pattern and returns it, while the match operator (`m//` aka `//`) preforms a regex match.

Since `qr//` always returns something true (a compiled regular expression), `return unless qr/\.jar$/;` will never return.

`=~ qr/\.jar$/` works because `=~` implies a match operator if the RHS operand isn't a match operator (`m//`), a substitution operator (`s///`) or a translate operator (`tr///`).

```
my $re = qr/\.jar$/;
$_ =~ $re
```

is short for

```
my $re = qr/\.jar$/;
$_ =~ /$re/
```

which is long for

```
my $re = qr/\.jar$/;
/$re/
```

If you omit both the `//` and the `=~`, you don't have a match operator anymore.

Comment: I guess the main thing is that `m/../` implicitly assumes a match against `$_` if you don't specify `=~` much like `-f` assumes it should test `$_` if you don't specify the variable to test. This is one of the few times I'll use this type of implicit `$_`. Normally, I'll tell people not to do this type of stuff because it'll break when you least expect it. Like in this situation.

Comment: You're still thinking about it all wrong. Why would a constant cause of a regex match? The main thing is that qr// doesn't cause any matching to happen at all. Added a bit to my answer to elaborate on this.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `qr//` doesn't match against anything until you tell it to.
(That's the only reason `qr//` is even part of the language)

```
my $match_jar = qr/\.jar$/;

$_ = undef;

print $match_jar, "\n" if $match_jar; # always prints

for( qw' matches.jar doesnt.txt ' ){
  print $_, "\n" if $_ =~ $match_jar; # only prints "matches.jar"

  # here is the reason qr// exists
  my $bool = /\.jar$/;
  print $bool, "\n"; # prints 1 or ''
}
```

```
(?^:\.jar$)
matches.jar
1
```

---

So how about instead of using [constant](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) you define the "constant" yourself.
(Note: [constant](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) actually just creates [inlinable subroutines](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html#TECHNICAL-NOTES), Perl doesn't really have constants.)

```
sub MATCH_JAR_FILE(_){ $_[0] =~ /\.jar$/ } # 5.10.0 or later

...
  # test against $_
  return unless MATCH_JAR_FILE;
...
  return unless MATCH_JAR_FILE($var);
...
```

Before [5.10](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#The-_-prototype) you will have to write it differently.

```
sub MATCH_JAR_FILE(;$){
  @_ = $_ unless @_; # doesn't get lexical $_
  $_[0] =~ /\.jar$/
}
```

Note that you will have to replace any occurrence of `... =~ JAR_FILE;` with `MATCH_JAR_FILE(...)`

---

If you don't mind using modules from [CPAN](http://cpan.org) you can use [Want](https://metacpan.org/module/Want). Then you will have another way to use the subroutine.

```
use Want 'want';

sub JAR_FILE(_){
  return $_[0] =~ /\.jar$/ if want 'BOOL';
  return qr/\.jar$/
}

...
  # test against $_
  return unless JAR_FILE; # bool
...
  return unless $var =~ JAR_FILE;
...
  return unless JAR_FILE($var); # bool
...
```

Before [5.10](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#The-_-prototype) you would probably write it quite differently.

```
use Want 'want';

sub JAR_FILE(){
  return /\.jar$/ if want 'BOOL';
  return qr/\.jar$/
}

...
  # test against $_
  return unless JAR_FILE; # bool
...
  return unless $var =~ JAR_FILE;
...
  # return unless JAR_FILE($var); # doesn't work
...
```